# How to open ERIM datafiles from Nielsen?

Tags: sas, enterprise-guide

https://research.chicagobooth.edu/kilts/marketing-databases/erim/erim-dataset

So I am looking at the Nielsen market data here, but cannot find a way to explore the data in this file using SAS EG. Does anyone have expertise in this? Thank you so much for reading the question and helping me out.

Answer (score 1):

The ERIM datasets are available as SAS Transport files, using the "SAS" files, or as text files, which you'd use the data description to know how to read.

SAS transport files (or at least, this variety of them) are brought in via PROC CIMPORT, which they include code for in the zip files.